# (Scala + RxJava3) Flowables.orderedMerge NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, rx-java, rx-java3

In Ammonite, I execute the following codes...
Trying to do an orderedMerge of two Flowables,

```
import $ivy.{
    `io.circe::circe-generic:0.13.0`                    ,
    `io.circe::circe-parser:0.13.0`                     ,
    `io.circe::circe-optics:0.13.0`                     ,
    `com.softwaremill.sttp::core:1.7.2`                 ,
    `org.scalaz::scalaz-core:7.2.27`                    ,
    `com.lihaoyi::requests:0.2.0`                       ,
    `io.get-coursier::coursier-core:2.0.0-RC4`          ,
    `io.lemonlabs::scala-uri:1.4.10`                    ,
    `net.liftweb::lift-json:3.4.0`                      ,
    `io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.3`                 ,
    `com.github.akarnokd:rxjava3-extensions:3.0.0-RC7`
}

import io.lemonlabs.uri._
implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._
import net.liftweb.json.Extraction._
import net.liftweb.json._
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core._
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._
import collection.JavaConverters._
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects._
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.functions.Functions
Flowables.orderedMerge(
    List(
        Flowable.just(3, 5),
        Flowable.just(2, 4, 6)
    ).toIterable.asJava, 
    Functions.naturalComparator[Int]()
    ).subscribe(i=>println(i))
```

But after printing 2, it throw exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.subscribers.InnerQueuedSubscriber.requestOne()V
  hu.akarnokd.rxjava3.operators.BasicMergeSubscription.drain(BasicMergeSubscription.java:268)
  hu.akarnokd.rxjava3.operators.BasicMergeSubscription.innerComplete(BasicMergeSubscription.java:161)
  io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.subscribers.InnerQueuedSubscriber.onSubscribe(InnerQueuedSubscriber.java:69)
  io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromArray.subscribeActual(FlowableFromArray.java:39)
  io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15750)
  io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15696)
  hu.akarnokd.rxjava3.operators.BasicMergeSubscription.subscribe(BasicMergeSubscription.java:79)
  hu.akarnokd.rxjava3.operators.FlowableOrderedMerge.subscribeActual(FlowableOrderedMerge.java:94)
  io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15750)
  io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15686)
  io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15618)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd63$.<clinit>(cmd63.sc:1)
```

Could anyone help me with it? I have no any idea about it...

The weird part is, it could print the first ordered item, but not the following ones...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rxjava3-extensions:3.0.0-RC7` is not compatible with `rxjava:3.0.3`. Release candidates don't provide strict compatibility guarantees.

Upgrade to `rxjava3-extensions:3.0.0` or up.

For future reference `NoSuchMethodError` almost always indicates incompatible libraries. The unfound method in the exception message and the method at the top of the stacktrace are good indicators of which libraries are involved.

Answer (score 0):

The original developer of the library told me to use the release version library, not to use the RC7. Then everything go well now.

Thanks all of you!

```
om.subscribe(i=>println(i)) 
2
3
4
5
6
res22: io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.Disposable = CANCELLED
```